# How do I call a non-static method from a static method from a different class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, static

I would like to call a non-static method from a static method located in a different class. I know the instance of the class from which I would like to call the method from but I am not able to access it.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Helper _Helper = new Helper(this);
    }
    public void DoSmth(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}

public class Helper
{
    MainForm _mainform = null;

    public Helper(MainForm mainform)
    {
        _mainform = mainform;
        _mainform.DoSmth("test"); //ok
    }
    public static void Test ()
    {
        _mainform.DoSmth("test"); //generates error
    }
}
```

Comment: The static method will either need the form handed to it as a parameter, or you'll need to construct a new instance inside the static method.

Comment: @asawyer or make `Helper.Test` non-static.

Comment: @DStanley Yeah I suppose that would also work, though it's not really what was asked. You could also make the `MainForm` instance inside the Helper type static now that I think about it.

Comment: why would you create an instance of ```Helper``` if you will use only static class methods?

Comment: @Jules I would presume this is a contrived example.

Comment: @asawyer probably...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not access non static context inside static context.

You can make `_mainform` static

```
static MainForm _mainform = null;
```

or pass the instance you want to test to `Test` method

```
public static void Test(MainForm mainForm)
{
    mainForm.DoSmth("test"); 
}
```

or make `Test` non static

```
public void Test()
{
    _mainform.DoSmth("test"); 
}
```

All aside you should revise your design. Think about these questions. If I have a static method why it should access an instance member? If a method should access instance members then why should it be static?